# c# DataSet - Using a unique constraint in place of a primary key

Tags: c#, dataset

Let's say I have two tables and I want to create a unique constraint for them across two columns:

```
    public static DataSet TmpEx()
    {
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

        dt1.Columns.Add("AlphaID");
        dt1.Columns.Add("ContainsNumID");

        dt1.Rows.Add("A", "123");
        dt1.Rows.Add("A", "222");
        dt1.Rows.Add("B", "123");
        dt1.Rows.Add("B", "333");

        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

        dt2.Columns.Add("NumberID");
        dt2.Columns.Add("ContainsNumber");

        dt2.Rows.Add("123", 1);
        dt2.Rows.Add("123", 2);
        dt2.Rows.Add("123", 3);
        dt2.Rows.Add("222", 2);
        dt2.Rows.Add("333", 3);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt1);
        ds.Tables.Add(dt2);

        DataColumn[] dcs = new DataColumn[2] { dt1.Columns[0], dt1.Columns[1] };

        dt1.Constraints.Add("UQ_AlphaID_NumID", dcs, true); 

        // ds.Relations.Add(dt1.Columns[1], dt2.Columns[1]);

        return ds;
    }
```

I have two issues here, right at the bottom of the code

- one is that I'm not even sure my "constraint" initiation is correct (does using the array of columns like that work?)
- second is that the compiler is telling me there are no unique columns in the relation - this is clearly true because it's a many-to-many relationship, but the many-to-many table doesn't exist because "AlphaID" and its "ContainsNumID" combo is always going to be unique. So can I implement this unique constraint in a datarelation or do I simply need to create a many-many relation table?!

Comment: You can view data by adding a break point after the dataset is built.  The hover over the variable ds.  Then click on the down arrow and select Data Set Visualizer.  There is a pulldown to select each of the tables.  The error indicates dt1 column 1 is a string while dt2 column 1 is an integer.  You can compare strings to integers.

Comment: What about creating them as a primary key?